Microsoft Access (2007-2016) - Form List Box Can't Be Found In Current Record?
I'm currently using Microsoft Access file format "Access 2007 - 2016".
What I'm trying to do is make a form with a combo box, that when a value is selected will populate a list box with results. I have a table with multiple fields, but two relevant ones specifically. The combo box has all possible names that could appear in Field A (drawn from a separate table), and the list box needs to display all values from Field B that correspond to the chosen name. Not all names from the combo box have a corresponding Field B value, and some names have multiple corresponding Field B values.
So far, I've got a macro that runs after the combo box is updated. The macro uses the OpenQuery action, then the Requery action directly after. My current problem resides in this Requery action. When I run the macro, I get an error stating that "There is no field named 'List Box A' in the current record." It also gives the error number: 2109. For the Requery's Control Name, I've triple checked that it's the same as the name shown in the list box's property sheet. What am I doing wrong?

You may have better luck with this at superuser.com, given that it sounds like your problem is more related to your form / macro, rather than a specific "database" issue

Oh okay, I'll post it there then. Thank you!
